# compare more than two strings

Tags: c, string, avr

I have 5 strings. I need to compere all five at once.

```
char set_password1[5] = "1111";
char set_password2[5] = "2222";
char set_password3[5] = "3333";
char set_password4[5] = "4444";
char set_password5[5] = "5555";

if(!strcmp(Entered_Password,set_password1))
{
}
```

If any of these passwords match with Enter _Password i need to do something. so do i have to write five if statements like this

```
if(!strcmp(Entered_Password,set_password1))
{
}
if(!strcmp(Entered_Password,set_password2))
{
}
if(!strcmp(Entered_Password,set_password3))
{
}
if(!strcmp(Entered_Password,set_password4))
{
}
if(!strcmp(Entered_Password,set_password5))
{
}
```

or is there any other way.
I already tried this way, but it didn't work.

```
if(!strcmp(Entered_Password, (set_password1||set_password2||set_password3||set_password4||set_password5))
{
}
```

Comment: Create an array of strings and loop through them?

Comment: You can match using loop concept

Comment: You cannot use a `switch`on strings...

Comment: `switch..case` is only applicable for integers and enumerated types in C.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Replace line

```
if(!strcmp(Entered_Password, (set_password1||set_password2||set_password3||set_password4||set_password5))
```

with

```
if (!(strcmp(Entered_Password, set_password1) && strcmp(Entered_Password,set_password2) && (strcmp(Entered_Password,set_password3) && strcmp(Entered_Password,set_password4) && strcmp(Entered_Password,set_password5)))
```

You have to compare each variable seperately with the initial string.

Comment: Didn't you mean `&&` ?

Comment: Poster said, "If any of these passwords match with Enter _Password i need to do something." ... So it should be || not && . @MohitJain

Comment: @MukitChowdhury Answer is corrected now. `strcmp` returns `0` if strings match. So by [de-morgan's law](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&client=ubuntu#q=de%20morgan%27s%20law), `||` become `&&`

Comment: Doesn't look much better than the original (rather, worse) - Just different.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you may use a 2D array.

```
char password[5][5] = {"1111", "22222", "3333", "44444", "55555"};
int match = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  if(strcmp(password[i], user_password) == 0)
  {
     match = 1;
     break;
  }
}

if(match == 1)
{
  //do your action
}
```